# Child Activity of ActivityGroup is not finished after finish() is called

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, activitygroup

I have a program using ActivityGroup. 
The class structure is as below:

```
Class A extends ActivityGroup {
onCreate(){
}
}

Class B extends A {
onCreate() {
startActivityResult();//launch C
}

onActivityResult(){
...
finish();//finish activity after receive result from C;this line of code does execute in test
...
}
}

Class C extends A {
onCreate(){
...
}
}
```

B is the entrance for the overall program.
In B's `onCreate()`, I use `startActivityResult()` to launch C; in C, it will show user a button; after user clicks the button, C will call `finish()` and `setResult();` then in B's `onActivityResult()`,
I try use the method `finish()` to exit all of the application.

The problem is that the screen turns into black after press the button. Then I use `hierarchyviewer.bat` too see the views; to my suprise, there are a view with id `R.id.content` and another root view without id. And the tools show that the activity B is on the top.
I know the view with id `R.id.content` is the root view of an `Activity`.But I don't know why it is still there after `finish()` is called. You know, there is no other logic after `finish()` and no other receiver there, or any other can block to finish.

Maybe it is an issue about my wrong use of `ActivityGroup`. Can anyone help?

Thanks for your answers for my first question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I know the root cause, that's because I used a singleTask activity of B but some other activities are started as new task and still not finished.